# How to have many objects of a class used as with Singleton?

Tags: c++, qt, singleton

Recently I developed a logger class for C++/Qt that was implemented as Singleton since each app using that class was supposed to have only one instance and, most importantly, I didn't want to have to copy pointers everywhere and neither pollute my code with lots of `extern`.

But a problem appeared when I started using it in a project that, having its own log, used of a library which would have its own log as well. I though that everything would work fine (after all the software is not the library being used), but I was wrong: actually only one instance of the log system was being created for both the app and the used library.

Now I'm facing this situation and, after multiple times, I was unable to get around: I don't want to have to use that class as one normally would use, declaring an object and start passing it everywhere with `extern`, but rather operate it as in Singleton: just #include the header and start calling the methods by a global instance() function. How can I do that without using Singleton in that logger class?

One way I figured out was to create a different Singleton class on each project (the lib and the main app) simply having an object of the logger class, but I'm interested in hearing other alternatives.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for the multi-singleton pattern, or perhaps a version of the severalton.

Comment: @KerrekSB I never heard of those, I'll have a look. Thanks!

Comment: Is your library a static or dynamic?

Comment: @S.T. Dynamic AFAIK ^^ (.so in Linux)

Answer (score 0):

Assign handle to every log instance and get log by instance. In library add function that returns handle for library, in application add function that returns handle for application log. And don't forget that singlton is hurd for use design pattern, avoid them.